# Unable to understand the result of RegEx split for a string

Tags: java, regex

I am running below 2 lines in Java (Java 8):

```
String dirTree = "dir\n\tsubdir1\n\tsubdir2\n\t\tfile.ext";
String[] result = dirTree.split("\\n\\t[^\\t]");
```

Result seen     - result:

```
["dir", "ubdir1", "ubdir2\n\t\tfile.ext"]
```

I was expecting - result:

```
["dir", "subdir1", "subdir2\n\t\tfile.ext"]
```

Can someone please explain why the first character of the strings in result are missing(Eg - "ubdir1" instead of "subdir1") ?

Comment: due to the following [^\t] in regex. Its splitting string on basis on newline followed by tab followed by non tab character

Comment: Because they are matched against `[^\t]`. (Everything that is not a tab)

Comment: try following expression "\n[\t]+" I believe this will do the desired split. Newline followed by any number of tas

Comment: Thanks, i understand why one non "\t" character is missing. But unable to get to a regex which gives me the result I am looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just Split by this :

```
\n\t(?!\t)
```

**Explanation:**

1. `\n\t` matches one newline and one tab
2. `(?!\t)` negative lookahead to ensure no \t followed immediately
   after `\n\t`

So the difference between `(?!\t)` and `[^\t]` is that the first one returns **true or false** and second one **matches** the character. So in your case, it matched the non tab character and used that to split as  well.

Answer (score 0):

You have to understand how the regex pattern works before applying it. 
Your regex pattern is `\n\t[^\t]` This search for a pattern with `\n\t` and any character except `\t`.  `[^\t]` negates the pattern. This pattern matches any character except `\t`. So in your case it is matching `s` because its is any character except `\t`.

To get your expected result your pattern should be `\n\t`